# Phase space density of $N$ harmonic oscillators

Tags: statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, phase-space, density-of-states

For one classical harmonic oscillator with Hamiltonian

$$H = \frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega^2}{2}x^2$$

the density of states can be calculated as by calculating the number of states with Energy smaller than $E$:

$$\Gamma(E) = \frac{\text{area of ellipse}}{h} = \frac{E}{\hbar \omega}$$

and then by carrying out the derivative $\frac{d\Gamma}{dE}$ one obtains: $g(E) = \frac{d\Gamma}{dE} = \frac{1}{\hbar \omega}$ as the density of states.

Now I wonder if it is possible to generalize this approach to a set of N harmonic oscillators, then with Hamiltonian:

$$H = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{p_i^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega^2}{2}x_i^2 $$

I can not "visualize" and understand how to calculate the area of this "ellipse" in the $2N$ dimensional phase space.

Comment: You can scale things so that the bounding surface becomes a hypersphere. The [volume of an n-ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball) is well-known and is probably somewhere in your textbook.

Comment: I see that it ist possible to obtain a hypersphere  for the free particle in 3d, as the hamiltonian then only depends on one variable. Is it then in the case of two variables in the hamiltonian I get two hyperspheres one for the x and one for the p variables?

Comment: You get a 6D hypersphere for one particle. The six axes in its phase space are $x,y,z,p_x,p_y,p_z$. By scaling you can make $H$ look like the sum of the squares of these coordinates. Scaling was the first hint in the problem you previously posted.

Answer (score 1):

The Hamiltonian of $N$ uncoupled oscillators,
$$E = \sum_{i=1}^N \left(\frac{p_i^2}{2m}+\frac{k x_i^2}{2}\right), $$
defines a $2N$-dimensional hyper-ellipsoid with semi axes $a_i = \sqrt{2mE}$, $b_i=\sqrt{2E/k}$, $i=1,\cdots N$.

The volume of an ellipsoid in $n$ dimensions is [(see Reference)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606184/volume-of-n-dimensional-ellipsoid)
\begin{gather}
  V_n = (c_1\cdots c_n) \frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}
\end{gather}
where $c_i$ are the $n$ semi axes and  $\Gamma(\cdots)$ is the gamma function (not to be confused with the common symbol for phase space).

The energy contour has $n=2N$ semiaxes of which $N$ are equal to $\sqrt{2mE}$ and $N$ are equal to $\sqrt{2E/k}$. Using $\Gamma(n/2+1) = \Gamma(N+1) = N!$, the number of microstates within the hyper-ellipsoid is
\begin{gather}
  \Omega(E) 
  = \frac{V_{2N}}{h^{2N} N!}
  = \left(\frac{2\pi}{h^2} \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}\right)^N 
    \frac{E^N}{(N!)^2} .
\end{gather}
This is the total number of microstates whose energy is less than or equal to $E$. The microcanonical partition function is its derivative with respect to $E$:
$$
\tag{1}
    \omega(E) = \frac{\partial\Omega}{\partial E} 
     = \frac{N}{(N!)^2}\left(\frac{2\pi}{h^2} \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}\right)^N 
       E^{N-1} . 
$$

**Canonical Partition Function** As a bonus, let's calculate the canonical partition function, which is simpler:
$$
   Q(\beta,N) = \int \omega(E,N) e^{-\beta E} dE 
  = Q(\beta,N) 
  = \frac{1}{N!}\left(\frac{2\pi}{\beta h^2} \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}\right)^N
$$
This we can write it in the equivalent form
$$
\tag{2}
\boxed{
  Q(\beta,N) = \frac{Q_1^N}{N!}
}
$$
where $Q_1$ is the canonical partition function of a single oscillator:
$$
  Q_1 = \frac{2\pi}{\beta h^2} \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}
$$
Equation 2 states that the partition function of $N$ oscillators is the product of $N$ independent partition functions corrected for indistinguishability. This is the expected result and serves as a check of the correctness of the derivation.

Answer (score 1):

> For one classical harmonic oscillator with Hamiltonian
> $$H = \frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega^2}{2}x^2$$

> The density of states can be calculated as by calculating the number of states with Energy smaller than $E$... and then by carrying out the derivative $\frac{d\Gamma}{dE}$ one obtains: $g(E) = \frac{d\Gamma}{dE} = \frac{1}{\hbar \omega}$ as the density of states.

> Now I wonder if it is possible to generalize this approach to a set of N harmonic oscillators, then with Hamiltonian:

Yes, it is possible.

A good first step is understanding how one arrives at
$\Gamma(E) = \frac{E}{\hbar \omega}$
for a single oscillator in one-dimension, in a way that can be generalized.

The result for the single oscillator follows from the usual method of counting states in phase space:
$$
\Gamma_1 = \int \frac{dxdp}{(2\pi\hbar)}\;,
$$
where the sub-script $1$ on $\Gamma_1$ means I am considering just one oscillator (in one dimension).

If you change variables to $u=x\sqrt{m\omega^2/2}$ and $v=p/\sqrt{2m}$, the integral for the number of states becomes:
$$
\Gamma_1 = \int \frac{du dv}{(2\pi\hbar)}|\frac{2}{\omega}|
$$

In the $(u,v)$ coordinates the condition that the energy is less than $E$ is simply $u^2 + v^2 < E$, which means we can write an expression for $\Gamma_1(E)$ as
$$
\Gamma_1(E) = 2\pi \int^\sqrt{E}_0 \frac{dr r}{(2\pi\hbar)}|\frac{2}{\omega}| = \frac{E}{\hbar \omega}
$$

---

Generalizing to $N$ oscillators in one dimension, we have:
$$
\Gamma_N = \frac{1}{N!}\int \frac{dx_1\ldots dp_N}{(2\pi \hbar)^N}\;.
$$

Making a similar substitution for each of the $N$ oscillators as done above with $u$ and $v$ gives:
$$
\Gamma_N(E) = \frac{1}{N!}\int \frac{du_1\ldots dv_N}{(2\pi \hbar)^N} |\frac{2}{\omega}|^N
 = \frac{1}{N!}|\frac{2}{\omega}|^N \frac{S_{2N}}{(2\pi \hbar)^N}\int_0^\sqrt{E} dr r^{2N-1}\tag{1}
\propto \frac{E^N}{(\hbar \omega)^N}\;,
$$
such that the density of states is
$$
g(E) \propto \frac{E^{N-1}}{(\hbar \omega)^N}\;.
$$

Note, if you want to work out the exact expression for $g(E)$ instead of just the proportionality above, you can use the fact that $S_{2N}$ in Eq. (1) above is the surface area of a sphere in $2N$ dimensions ($2\pi^N/(N-1)!$).

The above result is for $N$ oscillators in one spatial dimension. It also holds for one oscillator in $N$ spatial dimensions. The generalization to $A$ oscillators in $B$ spatial dimensions as well as the generalization to the case where the frequencies are not all the same is straightforward.